# hierarchical classification in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science

I would like to know if there is an implementation of hierarchical classification in the scikit-learn package or in any other python package.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270412/are-there-any-implementations-examples-of-hierarchical-classifiers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find an implementation of Hierarchical Classification on scikit-learn official documentation. But I found this repository recently. This module is based on scikit-learn's interfaces and conventions. I hope this will be useful.

https://github.com/globality-corp/sklearn-hierarchical-classification

Comment: Unfortunately, the repository was deleted has somebody a fork or an alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

The globality-corp repo was deleted, but I found this fork, so I am posting it:
https://github.com/fbenites/sklearn-hierarchical-classification

As above, it is a module following the scikit-learn's conventions and is used along with sklearn classifiers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: but it has some differences to what you get with pip install sklearn-hierarchical-classification